# Simplify the following expression into a single binomial coefficient.

Tags: combinatorics

For $k \le n$, simplify the following expression into a single binomial coefficient.

$C^k_3 + C^{n-k}_3 + (n-k)C^k_2 + kC^{n-k}_2$

=$\frac{k!}{(k-3)!3!} + \frac{(n-k)!}{(n-k-3)!3!} + \frac{k!(n-k)}{(k-2)!2!} + \frac{(n-k)!k}{(n-k-2)!2!}$

=$\frac{k(k-1)(k-2)}{3!} + \frac{(n-k)(n-k-1)(n-k-2)}{3!} + \frac{k(k-1)(n-k)}{2!} + \frac{k(n-k)(n-k-1)}{2!}$

Can give me hints? I tried expanding them to factorials. It looks like if i were to cancel of terms ill get no where.

Comment: Multiply by $6$ (to remove the denominator), expand, simplify and factor. All $k$ will disappear. Divide back by $6$.

Comment: Also, a question regarding notation: usually, the binomial coefficient "choose $k$ out of $n$" is written either $C_n^k$ or ${n \choose k}$. However, you seem to be writing this $C_k^n$. Is this a mistake? If it's not, I'd be interested to know in which country/institution it is customary, as I was not aware of this.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think the more common way is $C(n,k)$ [wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_k-combinations) for different variations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

Suppose you have $n$ pens. Suppose $k$ of them are blue, $n-k$ of them are red. The number of ways to choose 3 pens is
$$
n \choose 3
$$
Now you have 4 cases

- 3 blue pen: $k \choose 3$
- 3 red pen: $n-k \choose 3$
- 2 blue 1 red : $(n-k) {k \choose 2}$
- 1 blue 2 red : $k {n-k \choose 2}$